# How can I use my MySQL Database on another computer (using a java program)

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have finally finished a Java program that uses MySQL database with 3 tables. The problem is that I have very little knowledge on both Java and MySQL.

I basically have to send my program to an examiner and it has to work when the examiner tries to use it. How will this work with my database from MySQL? In the beginning, I thought that MySQL stores the data online and that it wouldn't be a problem because it can be accessed through my program/internet.

However, when I run the program without any internet connection, it still works on my computer which leads me to believe that the database is stored on my computer.

Some info: I am using MySQL workbench but have very little knowledge about it and my program connects to my database using a connection function and prepared statements.MySQl workbench is telling me that my database connection is hosted by my computer

My connection method is in this way:

```
    try{
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = ".....;
        String username ="..";
        String password = "..";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        return conn;
        }
```

How can I make my program run on another computer if the database is (presumably) stored on my computer? Do I need to export my database? Upload it?

Note: I am a noob. sorry

Comment: arent you missing a ""?

Comment: Would do you mean @ProgrammingNewb

Comment: string url = "....; and then everything else is inside the string, you didnt close your quotes

Comment: True thats just because i deleted the content :=). Accident